# Is this also a list question?

Tags: discussion

[Besides practicing, what are some great ways to become a better player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/besides-practicing-what-are-some-great-ways-to-become-a-better-player)

Subjective? It's not answerable, because anything anyone says is equally valid.

Comment: Relevant: [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: Nope.  Not a list question.  Subjective as hell, though.

Comment: Well, removing community wiki from the question is a good start.

Answer (score -2):

For this question we have the luxury of looking at the answers the question *did* have, rather than having to close based on the answers the question *would* have.

Is the question – and thus the answers – just about the *what* or also about the *why* and *how?*

The answer is: **...kinda.** The question certainly elicited for a list of ways to improve your game, and the fact it provides a bunch of links of its own is a pretty bad smell. The FAQ says:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>     answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

This is nothing that can't be fixed with some editing; however, the question does seem rather... light on details once you do.

All of the answers are pretty list-y, but most of the answers do explain why they encourage the suggested resources and methods. There's, all in all, nothing unsalvageable here.

I'm open to three possibilities:

1. Historical lock, which I'd rather avoid due to link rot
2. Editing those posts until we like them.
3. Asking a new question that better suits our standards, reorganizing the wealth of knowledge in there according to our newer standards, then deleting the original question.